# How to search / open a file type without knowing the file name

Tags: windows, cmd, command-line, command-prompt

I'm trying to write an alias for my cmder to quickly open a certain file. Usually I navigate to my desired directory and type 'code .' to open the project in vscode. However some projects are in visual studio, so I cannot use 'code .' I'm trying to write an alias that when typed will find the file that ends in '.sln', the file ending for visual studio projects, and then open it.

I tried piping `dir /b *.sln` into `start` like:

`start | dir /b *.sln`

but this simply opened a new empty tab for cmder, I'm not sure why.

Is there a way to pipe this? Or possibly is there another method to do this? (maybe theres parameters for 'start' that will allow me to do this that I don't know about).

Comment: It might be easy or even very easy. What's the output of `assoc .sln`?

Answer (score 0):

So, can try this...

in command line:

```bat
for /f ^tokens^=* %i in ('""%__APPDIR__%where.exe" /r . "*.sln""')do start "" "%~i"
```

or, in bat/cmd file:

```bat
for /f ^tokens^=* %%i in ('""%__APPDIR__%where.exe" /r . "*.sln""')do start "" "%%~i"
```

---

For more information/help on for, where and start commands, try:

```bat
>"%temp%\help_cmds.txt" (for /? & where /? & start /?) & "%temp%\help_cmds.txt"
```

This command will get help from the commands and will be saved in the txt file that will open..